# CSS: Vertical menu not scrollable when multiple elements opened

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having a problem with scrolling on the mobile version (1299px @media defined rule) of the vertical menu on my website. Link is: https://my-digital.ro/wp/

Video explaining problem: https://youtu.be/K9fQJPb6WMI

So basically, my issue is that I am trying to make the whole menu scrollable on mobile. It worked fine when I added **overflow: scroll** property to the elements, except that it does not work when a sub-menu is expanded. It just gets stuck, as it was **overflow: hidden** and I can not scroll further.

Actual CSS is:

```
.clearfix {
display:block;
clear: both;
position: sticky;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1299px) {
#content {
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:0px;
    z-index:102
}
#main-nav {
    overflow: scroll;
}
.clearfix {
    overflow: scroll;
}
header {
    position:fixed;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto; }
```

I have tried adding overflow:scroll even to the header elements inside @1299px rule and others too, including **ul> li .submenu** but nothing works :(.

Answer (score 0):

Just make these changes in your style.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1299px)
#main-nav {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Where, exactly?

Comment: actually you are not providing actual length of your menu

Answer (score 0):

give some relative height to the main_nav:

```
#main-nav {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 90vh;
}
```

where `vh` is relative to 1% of the height of the viewport.

And please use `overflow: auto;` instead of `overflow: scroll;`